File path good for Windows and Android
I have a python script that uses images from a folder. The script might work on Windows and Android as well. The problem is I should indicate different file path for the same images (included in the folder where the script is). Is there a format I can use valid for both?
For Android I am using "./image.png", but this does not work on Windows.

If you want some dynamic path, you can use os:
import os
path = os.path.join('folder1', 'folder2', '...', 'image.png')

You can use as many as you need, or just image.png.

For an OS-independent access to files and path handling, you could use Path objects from the built-in pathlib library.
In your case, you could use, for example:
from pathlib import Path

image_path = Path(__file__).parent / "image.png"

The code does the following:

With Path(__file__), you get the path to your current script.
With .parent, you get the parent directory, so the directory that your current script is in.
With / "image.png". You get the path to the file "image.png" in this directory.

Note that in the context of Path objects, the separator / is used system-independent, and will be interpreted correctly as slash or backslash once the Path object is used to actually access a file.
Nowadays, most functions and libraries that deal with file access directly accept Path objects just like strings as file locations. If you need a string, however, you can simply convert the Path instance image_path with str(image_path).
